# C言語を用いたディープラーニング

Tags: c, 機械学習, 深層学習

[C/C++によるDeep Learningの実装（Deep Belief Nets, Stacked Denoising Autoencoders 編） - Yusuke Sugomori's Blog](http://blog.yusugomori.com/post/43636583955/cc-%E3%81%AB%E3%82%88%E3%82%8Bdeep-learning%E3%81%AE%E5%AE%9F%E8%A3%85deep-belief-nets-stacked) にある、DBN.cを参考にしています。
DBN.cを少し変えて、トレーニングデータにdouble型のデータを入力できるように変えたつもりなのですが、うまくいきません。どこが間違っているのでしょうか?
用いるデータはフリーデータirisを0~1の間に収まるように変換したものです。

期待した結果
テストデータごとにあるクラスへの出力が大きくなり、クラスの判別率が高い。
下記に載せている、トレーニングラベルのような出力を期待していました。

```
0.900   0.050   0.050 
0.900   0.040   0.060
          : 
0.040   0.900   0.060 
0.100   0.850   0.050
          : 
0.050   0.100   0.850
```

実際
クラスへの出力がほとんど同じで、判別率が約33%とチャンスレベルになっている。
どのテストデータについても同じ値を返している。

```
0.32467 0.33520 0.34013 
0.32467 0.33520 0.34013 
文字数の関係で省略しています。
0.32467 0.33520 0.34014
```

コード
DBNTrainingDouble.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void readFileData(const char *fileName,double array[][4]){
    FILE *fp ;
    int row,inData;
    if((fp=fopen(fileName,"r"))!=NULL){
        row=0;
        while(4==fscanf(fp,"%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf",&array[row][0],&array[row][1],&array[row][2],&array[row][3])){
            row++;
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }else{
        printf("Open error!!\n");
    }
}

void readFileLabel(const char *fileName,int array[][3]){
    FILE *fp ;
    int row,inData;
    if((fp=fopen(fileName,"r"))!=NULL){
        row=0;
        while(3==fscanf(fp,"%d,%d,%d",&array[row][0],&array[row][1],&array[row][2],&array[row][3])){
            row++;
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }else{
        printf("Open error!!\n");
    }
}

/* HiddenLayer.h */
typedef struct {
  int N;
  int n_in;
  int n_out;
  double **W;
  double *b;
} HiddenLayer;

void HiddenLayer__construct(HiddenLayer*, int, int, int, double**, double*);
void HiddenLayer__destruct(HiddenLayer*);
double HiddenLayer_output(HiddenLayer*, double*, double*, double);
void HiddenLayer_sample_h_given_v(HiddenLayer*, double*, double*);

/* RBM.h */
typedef struct {
  int N;
  int n_visible;
  int n_hidden;
  double **W;
  double *hbias;
  double *vbias;
} RBM;

void RBM__construct(RBM*, int, int, int, double**, double*, double*);
void RBM__destruct(RBM*);
void RBM_contrastive_divergence(RBM*, double*, double, int);
void RBM_sample_h_given_v(RBM*, double*, double*, double*);
void RBM_sample_v_given_h(RBM*, double*, double*, double*);
double RBM_propup(RBM*, double*, double*, double);
double RBM_propdown(RBM*, double*, int, double);
void RBM_gibbs_hvh(RBM*, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*);
void RBM_reconstruct(RBM*, double*, double*);

/* LogisticRegression.h */
typedef struct {
  int N;
  int n_in;
  int n_out;
  double **W;
  double *b;
} LogisticRegression;

void LogisticRegression__construct(LogisticRegression*, int, int, int);
void LogisticRegression__destruct(LogisticRegression*);
void LogisticRegression_train(LogisticRegression*, double*, int*, double);
void LogisticRegression_softmax(LogisticRegression*, double*);
void LogisticRegression_predict(LogisticRegression*, double*, double*);

/* DBN.h */
typedef struct {
  int N;
  int n_ins;
  int *hidden_layer_sizes;
  int n_outs;
  int n_layers;
  HiddenLayer *sigmoid_layers;
  RBM *rbm_layers;
  LogisticRegression log_layer;
} DBN;

void DBN__construct(DBN*, int, int, int*, int, int);
void DBN__destruct(DBN*);
void DBN_pretrain(DBN*, double*, double, int, int);
void DBN_finetune(DBN*, double*, int*, double, int);
void DBN_predict(DBN*, double*, double*);

/* utils.h */
double uniform(double, double);
int binomial(int, double);
double sigmoid(double);

void test_dbn(void);

double uniform(double min, double max) {
  return rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0) * (max - min) + min;  
}

int binomial(int n, double p) {
  if(p < 0 || p > 1) return 0;

  int i;
  int c = 0;
  double r;

  for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
    r = rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0);
    if (r < p) c++;
  }

  return c;
}

double sigmoid(double x) {
  return 1.0 / (1.0 + exp(-x));
}

// DBN
void DBN__construct(DBN* this, int N, \
                    int n_ins, int *hidden_layer_sizes, int n_outs, int n_layers) {
  int i, input_size;

  this->N = N;
  this->n_ins = n_ins;
  this->hidden_layer_sizes = hidden_layer_sizes;
  this->n_outs = n_outs;
  this->n_layers = n_layers;

  this->sigmoid_layers = (HiddenLayer *)malloc(sizeof(HiddenLayer) * n_layers);
  this->rbm_layers = (RBM *)malloc(sizeof(RBM) * n_layers);

  // construct multi-layer
  for(i=0; i<n_layers; i++) {
    if(i == 0) {
      input_size = n_ins;
    } else {
      input_size = hidden_layer_sizes[i - 1];
    }

    // construct sigmoid_layer
    HiddenLayer__construct(&(this->sigmoid_layers[i]), \
                           N, input_size, hidden_layer_sizes[i], NULL, NULL);

    // construct rbm_layer
    RBM__construct(&(this->rbm_layers[i]), N, input_size, hidden_layer_sizes[i], \
                   this->sigmoid_layers[i].W, this->sigmoid_layers[i].b, NULL);

  }

  // layer for output using LogisticRegression
  LogisticRegression__construct(&(this->log_layer), \
                                N, hidden_layer_sizes[n_layers-1], n_outs);

}

void DBN__destruct(DBN* this) {
  int i;
  for(i=0; i<this->n_layers; i++) {
    HiddenLayer__destruct(&(this->sigmoid_layers[i]));
    RBM__destruct(&(this->rbm_layers[i]));
  }
  free(this->sigmoid_layers);
  free(this->rbm_layers);
}

void DBN_pretrain(DBN* this, double *input, double lr, int k, int epochs) {
  int i, j, l, m, n, epoch;

  double *layer_input;
  int prev_layer_input_size;
  double *prev_layer_input;

  double *train_X = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * this->n_ins);

  for(i=0; i<this->n_layers; i++) { // layer-wise

    for(epoch=0; epoch<epochs; epoch++) { // training epochs

      for(n=0; n<this->N; n++) { // input x1...xN
        // initial input
        for(m=0; m<this->n_ins; m++) train_X[m] = input[n * this->n_ins + m];

        // layer input
        for(l=0; l<=i; l++) {
          if(l == 0) {
            layer_input = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * this->n_ins);
            for(j=0; j<this->n_ins; j++) layer_input[j] = train_X[j];
          } else {
            if(l == 1) prev_layer_input_size = this->n_ins;
            else prev_layer_input_size = this->hidden_layer_sizes[l-2];

            prev_layer_input = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * prev_layer_input_size);
            for(j=0; j<prev_layer_input_size; j++) prev_layer_input[j] = layer_input[j];
            free(layer_input);

            layer_input = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * this->hidden_layer_sizes[l-1]);

            HiddenLayer_sample_h_given_v(&(this->sigmoid_layers[l-1]), \
                                         prev_layer_input, layer_input);
            free(prev_layer_input);
          }
        }

        RBM_contrastive_divergence(&(this->rbm_layers[i]), layer_input, lr, k);
      }

    }
  }

  free(train_X);
  free(layer_input);
}

void DBN_finetune(DBN* this, double *input, int *label, double lr, int epochs) {
  int i, j, m, n, epoch;

  double *layer_input;
  int prev_layer_input_size;
  double *prev_layer_input;

  double *train_X = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * this->n_ins);
  int *train_Y = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * this->n_outs);

  for(epoch=0; epoch<epochs; epoch++) {
    for(n=0; n<this->N; n++) { // input x1...xN
      // initial input
      for(m=0; m<this->n_ins; m++)  train_X[m] = input[n * this->n_ins + m];
      for(m=0; m<this->n_outs; m++) train_Y[m] = label[n * this->n_outs + m];

      // layer input
      for(i=0; i<this->n_layers; i++) {
        if(i == 0) {
          prev_layer_input = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * this->n_ins);
          for(j=0; j<this->n_ins; j++) prev_layer_input[j] = train_X[j];
        } else {
          prev_layer_input = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * this->hidden_layer_sizes[i-1]);
          for(j=0; j<this->hidden_layer_sizes[i-1]; j++) prev_layer_input[j] = layer_input[j];
          free(layer_input);
        }


        layer_input = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * this->hidden_layer_sizes[i]);
        HiddenLayer_sample_h_given_v(&(this->sigmoid_layers[i]), \
                                     prev_layer_input, layer_input);
        free(prev_layer_input);
      }

      LogisticRegression_train(&(this->log_layer), layer_input, train_Y, lr);
    }
    // lr *= 0.95;
  }

  free(layer_input);
  free(train_X);
  free(train_Y);
}

void DBN_predict(DBN* this, double *x, double *y) {
  int i, j, k;
  double *layer_input;
  int prev_layer_input_size;
  double *prev_layer_input;

  double linear_output;

  prev_layer_input = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * this->n_ins);
  for(j=0; j<this->n_ins; j++) prev_layer_input[j] = x[j];

  // layer activation
  for(i=0; i<this->n_layers; i++) {
    layer_input = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * this->sigmoid_layers[i].n_out);

    for(k=0; k<this->sigmoid_layers[i].n_out; k++) {
      linear_output = 0.0;

      for(j=0; j<this->sigmoid_layers[i].n_in; j++) {
        linear_output += this->sigmoid_layers[i].W[k][j] * prev_layer_input[j];
      }
      linear_output += this->sigmoid_layers[i].b[k];
      layer_input[k] = sigmoid(linear_output);
    }
    free(prev_layer_input);

    if(i < this->n_layers-1) {
      prev_layer_input = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * this->sigmoid_layers[i].n_out);
      for(j=0; j<this->sigmoid_layers[i].n_out; j++) prev_layer_input[j] = layer_input[j];
      free(layer_input);
    }
  }

  for(i=0; i<this->log_layer.n_out; i++) {
    y[i] = 0;
    for(j=0; j<this->log_layer.n_in; j++) {
      y[i] += this->log_layer.W[i][j] * layer_input[j];
    }
    y[i] += this->log_layer.b[i];
  }

  LogisticRegression_softmax(&(this->log_layer), y);

  free(layer_input);
}

// HiddenLayer
void HiddenLayer__construct(HiddenLayer* this, int N, int n_in, int n_out, \
                            double **W, double *b) {
  int i, j;
  double a = 1.0 / n_in;

  this->N = N;
  this->n_in = n_in;
  this->n_out = n_out;

  if(W == NULL) {
    this->W = (double **)malloc(sizeof(double*) * n_out);
    this->W[0] = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * n_in * n_out);
    for(i=0; i<n_out; i++) this->W[i] = this->W[0] + i * n_in;

    for(i=0; i<n_out; i++) {
      for(j=0; j<n_in; j++) {
        this->W[i][j] = uniform(-a, a);
      }
    }
  } else {
    this->W = W;
  }

  if(b == NULL) {
    this->b = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * n_out);
  } else {
    this->b = b;
  }
}

void HiddenLayer__destruct(HiddenLayer* this) {
  free(this->W[0]);
  free(this->W);
  free(this->b);
}

double HiddenLayer_output(HiddenLayer* this, double *input, double *w, double b) {
  int j;
  double linear_output = 0.0;
  for(j=0; j<this->n_in; j++) {
    linear_output += w[j] * input[j];
  }
  linear_output += b;
  return sigmoid(linear_output);
}

void HiddenLayer_sample_h_given_v(HiddenLayer* this, double *input, double *sample) {
  int i;
  for(i=0; i<this->n_out; i++) {
    sample[i] = binomial(1, HiddenLayer_output(this, input, this->W[i], this->b[i]));
  }
}


// RBM
void RBM__construct(RBM* this, int N, int n_visible, int n_hidden, \
                    double **W, double *hbias, double *vbias) {
  int i, j;
  double a = 1.0 / n_visible;

  this->N = N;
  this->n_visible = n_visible;
  this->n_hidden = n_hidden;

  if(W == NULL) {
    this->W = (double **)malloc(sizeof(double*) * n_hidden);
    this->W[0] = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * n_visible * n_hidden);
    for(i=0; i<n_hidden; i++) this->W[i] = this->W[0] + i * n_visible;

    for(i=0; i<n_hidden; i++) {
      for(j=0; j<n_visible; j++) {
        this->W[i][j] = uniform(-a, a);
      }
    }
  } else {
    this->W = W;
  }

  if(hbias == NULL) {
    this->hbias = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * n_hidden);
    for(i=0; i<n_hidden; i++) this->hbias[i] = 0;
  } else {
    this->hbias = hbias;
  }

  if(vbias == NULL) {
    this->vbias = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * n_visible);
    for(i=0; i<n_visible; i++) this->vbias[i] = 0;
  } else {
    this->vbias = vbias;
  }
}

void RBM__destruct(RBM* this) {
  // free(this->W[0]);
  // free(this->W);
  // free(this->hbias);
  free(this->vbias);
}

void RBM_contrastive_divergence(RBM* this, double *input, double lr, int k) {
  int i, j, step;

  double *ph_mean = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * this->n_hidden);
  double *ph_sample = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * this->n_hidden);
  double *nv_means = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * this->n_visible);
  double *nv_samples = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * this->n_visible);
  double *nh_means = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * this->n_hidden);
  double *nh_samples = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * this->n_hidden);

  /* CD-k */
  RBM_sample_h_given_v(this, input, ph_mean, ph_sample);

  for(step=0; step<k; step++) {
    if(step == 0) {
      RBM_gibbs_hvh(this, ph_sample, nv_means, nv_samples, nh_means, nh_samples);
    } else {
      RBM_gibbs_hvh(this, nh_samples, nv_means, nv_samples, nh_means, nh_samples);
    }
  }

  for(i=0; i<this->n_hidden; i++) {
    for(j=0; j<this->n_visible; j++) {
      // this->W[i][j] += lr * (ph_sample[i] * input[j] - nh_means[i] * nv_samples[j]) / this->N;
      this->W[i][j] += lr * (ph_mean[i] * input[j] - nh_means[i] * nv_samples[j]) / this->N;
    }
    this->hbias[i] += lr * (ph_sample[i] - nh_means[i]) / this->N;
  }

  for(i=0; i<this->n_visible; i++) {
    this->vbias[i] += lr * (input[i] - nv_samples[i]) / this->N;
  }


  free(ph_mean);
  free(ph_sample);
  free(nv_means);
  free(nv_samples);
  free(nh_means);
  free(nh_samples);
}


void RBM_sample_h_given_v(RBM* this, double *v0_sample, double *mean, double *sample) {
  int i;
  for(i=0; i<this->n_hidden; i++) {
    mean[i] = RBM_propup(this, v0_sample, this->W[i], this->hbias[i]);
    sample[i] = binomial(1, mean[i]);
  }
}

void RBM_sample_v_given_h(RBM* this, double *h0_sample, double *mean, double *sample) {
  int i;
  for(i=0; i<this->n_visible; i++) {
    mean[i] = RBM_propdown(this, h0_sample, i, this->vbias[i]);
    sample[i] = binomial(1, mean[i]);
  }
}

double RBM_propup(RBM* this, double *v, double *w, double b) {
  int j;
  double pre_sigmoid_activation = 0.0;
  for(j=0; j<this->n_visible; j++) {
    pre_sigmoid_activation += w[j] * v[j];
  }
  pre_sigmoid_activation += b;
  return sigmoid(pre_sigmoid_activation);
}

double RBM_propdown(RBM* this, double *h, int i, double b) {
  int j;
  double pre_sigmoid_activation = 0.0;

  for(j=0; j<this->n_hidden; j++) {
    pre_sigmoid_activation += this->W[j][i] * h[j];
  }
  pre_sigmoid_activation += b;
  return sigmoid(pre_sigmoid_activation);
}

void RBM_gibbs_hvh(RBM* this, double *h0_sample, double *nv_means, double *nv_samples, \
                   double *nh_means, double *nh_samples) {
  RBM_sample_v_given_h(this, h0_sample, nv_means, nv_samples);
  RBM_sample_h_given_v(this, nv_samples, nh_means, nh_samples);
}

void RBM_reconstruct(RBM* this, double *v, double *reconstructed_v) {
  int i, j;
  double *h = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * this->n_hidden);
  double pre_sigmoid_activation;

  for(i=0; i<this->n_hidden; i++) {
    h[i] = RBM_propup(this, v, this->W[i], this->hbias[i]);
  }

  for(i=0; i<this->n_visible; i++) {
    pre_sigmoid_activation = 0.0;
    for(j=0; j<this->n_hidden; j++) {
      pre_sigmoid_activation += this->W[j][i] * h[j];
    }
    pre_sigmoid_activation += this->vbias[i];

    reconstructed_v[i] = sigmoid(pre_sigmoid_activation);
  }

  free(h);
}


// LogisticRegression
void LogisticRegression__construct(LogisticRegression *this, int N, int n_in, int n_out) {
  int i, j;
  this->N = N;
  this->n_in = n_in;
  this->n_out = n_out;

  this->W = (double **)malloc(sizeof(double*) * n_out);
  this->W[0] = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * n_in * n_out);
  for(i=0; i<n_out; i++) this->W[i] = this->W[0] + i * n_in;
  this->b = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * n_out);

  for(i=0; i<n_out; i++) {
    for(j=0; j<n_in; j++) {
      this->W[i][j] = 0;
    }
    this->b[i] = 0;
  }
}

void LogisticRegression__destruct(LogisticRegression *this) {
  free(this->W[0]);
  free(this->W);
  free(this->b);
}

void LogisticRegression_train(LogisticRegression *this, double *x, int *y, double lr) {
  int i,j;
  double *p_y_given_x = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * this->n_out);
  double *dy = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * this->n_out);

  for(i=0; i<this->n_out; i++) {
    p_y_given_x[i] = 0;
    for(j=0; j<this->n_in; j++) {
      p_y_given_x[i] += this->W[i][j] * x[j];
    }
    p_y_given_x[i] += this->b[i];
  }
  LogisticRegression_softmax(this, p_y_given_x);

  for(i=0; i<this->n_out; i++) {
    dy[i] = y[i] - p_y_given_x[i];

    for(j=0; j<this->n_in; j++) {
      this->W[i][j] += lr * dy[i] * x[j] / this->N;
    }

    this->b[i] += lr * dy[i] / this->N;
  }

  free(p_y_given_x);
  free(dy);
}

void LogisticRegression_softmax(LogisticRegression *this, double *x) {
  int i;
  double max = 0.0;
  double sum = 0.0;

  for(i=0; i<this->n_out; i++) if(max < x[i]) max = x[i];
  for(i=0; i<this->n_out; i++) {
    x[i] = exp(x[i] - max);
    sum += x[i];
  }

  for(i=0; i<this->n_out; i++) x[i] /= sum;
}

void LogisticRegression_predict(LogisticRegression *this, double *x, double *y) {
  int i,j;

  for(i=0; i<this->n_out; i++) {
    y[i] = 0;
    for(j=0; j<this->n_in; j++) {
      y[i] += this->W[i][j] * x[j];
    }
    y[i] += this->b[i];
  }

  LogisticRegression_softmax(this, y);
}


void test_dbn(void) {
  srand(0);

  int i, j;

  double pretrain_lr = 0.1;
  int pretraining_epochs = 1000;
  int k = 1;
  double finetune_lr = 0.1;
  int finetune_epochs = 500;

  int train_N = 75;
  int test_N = 75;
  int n_ins = 4;
  int n_outs = 3;
  int hidden_layer_sizes[] = {3, 3, 3};
  int n_layers = sizeof(hidden_layer_sizes) / sizeof(hidden_layer_sizes[0]);

  double train_X[75][4];
  int train_Y[75][3];
  double test_X[75][4];
  double test_Y[75][3];

  readFileData("trainingData.csv",train_X);
  readFileLabel("trainingLabel.csv",train_Y);
  readFileData("testData.csv",test_X);

  // construct DBN
  DBN dbn;
  DBN__construct(&dbn, train_N, n_ins, hidden_layer_sizes, n_outs, n_layers);

  // pretrain
  DBN_pretrain(&dbn, *train_X, pretrain_lr, k, pretraining_epochs);

  // finetune
  DBN_finetune(&dbn, *train_X, *train_Y, finetune_lr, finetune_epochs);

  // test
  for(i=0; i<test_N; i++) {
    DBN_predict(&dbn, test_X[i], test_Y[i]);
    for(j=0; j<n_outs; j++) {
      printf("%.5f ", test_Y[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  // destruct DBN
  DBN__destruct(&dbn);

}



int main(void) {
  test_dbn();
  return 0;
}
```

トレーニングデータ(irisの奇数行)
trainingData.csv

```
0.222222222,0.625,0.06779661,0.041666667
0.111111111,0.5,0.050847458,0.041666667
0.194444444,0.666666667,0.06779661,0.041666667
0.083333333,0.583333333,0.06779661,0.083333333
0.027777778,0.375,0.06779661,0.041666667
0.305555556,0.708333333,0.084745763,0.041666667
0.138888889,0.416666667,0.06779661,0
0.416666667,0.833333333,0.033898305,0.041666667
0.305555556,0.791666667,0.050847458,0.125
0.388888889,0.75,0.118644068,0.083333333
0.305555556,0.583333333,0.118644068,0.041666667
0.083333333,0.666666667,0,0.041666667
0.138888889,0.583333333,0.152542373,0.041666667
0.194444444,0.583333333,0.101694915,0.125
0.25,0.583333333,0.06779661,0.041666667
0.138888889,0.458333333,0.101694915,0.041666667
0.25,0.875,0.084745763,0
0.166666667,0.458333333,0.084745763,0.041666667
0.333333333,0.625,0.050847458,0.041666667
0.027777778,0.416666667,0.050847458,0.041666667
0.194444444,0.625,0.050847458,0.083333333
0.027777778,0.5,0.050847458,0.041666667
0.222222222,0.75,0.152542373,0.125
0.222222222,0.75,0.101694915,0.041666667
0.277777778,0.708333333,0.084745763,0.041666667
0.75,0.5,0.627118644,0.541666667
0.722222222,0.458333333,0.661016949,0.583333333
0.611111111,0.333333333,0.610169492,0.583333333
0.555555556,0.541666667,0.627118644,0.625
0.638888889,0.375,0.610169492,0.5
0.194444444,0,0.423728814,0.375
0.472222222,0.083333333,0.508474576,0.375
0.361111111,0.375,0.440677966,0.5
0.361111111,0.416666667,0.593220339,0.583333333
0.527777778,0.083333333,0.593220339,0.583333333
0.444444444,0.5,0.644067797,0.708333333
0.555555556,0.208333333,0.661016949,0.583333333
0.583333333,0.375,0.559322034,0.5
0.694444444,0.333333333,0.644067797,0.541666667
0.472222222,0.375,0.593220339,0.583333333
0.333333333,0.166666667,0.474576271,0.416666667
0.416666667,0.291666667,0.491525424,0.458333333
0.305555556,0.416666667,0.593220339,0.583333333
0.666666667,0.458333333,0.627118644,0.583333333
0.361111111,0.416666667,0.525423729,0.5
0.333333333,0.25,0.576271186,0.458333333
0.416666667,0.25,0.508474576,0.458333333
0.361111111,0.291666667,0.542372881,0.5
0.388888889,0.375,0.542372881,0.5
0.222222222,0.208333333,0.338983051,0.416666667
0.555555556,0.541666667,0.847457627,1
0.777777778,0.416666667,0.830508475,0.833333333
0.611111111,0.416666667,0.813559322,0.875
0.166666667,0.208333333,0.593220339,0.666666667
0.666666667,0.208333333,0.813559322,0.708333333
0.611111111,0.5,0.694915254,0.791666667
0.694444444,0.416666667,0.762711864,0.833333333
0.416666667,0.333333333,0.694915254,0.958333333
0.611111111,0.416666667,0.762711864,0.708333333
0.944444444,0.25,1,0.916666667
0.722222222,0.5,0.796610169,0.916666667
0.944444444,0.333333333,0.966101695,0.791666667
0.666666667,0.541666667,0.796610169,0.833333333
0.527777778,0.333333333,0.644067797,0.708333333
0.583333333,0.333333333,0.779661017,0.833333333
0.861111111,0.333333333,0.86440678,0.75
0.583333333,0.333333333,0.779661017,0.875
0.5,0.25,0.779661017,0.541666667
0.555555556,0.583333333,0.779661017,0.958333333
0.472222222,0.416666667,0.644067797,0.708333333
0.666666667,0.458333333,0.779661017,0.958333333
0.416666667,0.291666667,0.694915254,0.75
0.666666667,0.541666667,0.796610169,1
0.555555556,0.208333333,0.677966102,0.75
0.527777778,0.583333333,0.745762712,0.916666667
```

トレーニングラベル
trainingLabel.csv

```
1,0,0
1,0,0
1,0,0
1,0,0
1,0,0
1,0,0
1,0,0
1,0,0
1,0,0
1,0,0
1,0,0
1,0,0
1,0,0
1,0,0
1,0,0
1,0,0
1,0,0
1,0,0
1,0,0
1,0,0
1,0,0
1,0,0
1,0,0
1,0,0
1,0,0
0,1,0
0,1,0
0,1,0
0,1,0
0,1,0
0,1,0
0,1,0
0,1,0
0,1,0
0,1,0
0,1,0
0,1,0
0,1,0
0,1,0
0,1,0
0,1,0
0,1,0
0,1,0
0,1,0
0,1,0
0,1,0
0,1,0
0,1,0
0,1,0
0,1,0
0,0,1
0,0,1
0,0,1
0,0,1
0,0,1
0,0,1
0,0,1
0,0,1
0,0,1
0,0,1
0,0,1
0,0,1
0,0,1
0,0,1
0,0,1
0,0,1
0,0,1
0,0,1
0,0,1
0,0,1
0,0,1
0,0,1
0,0,1
0,0,1
0,0,1
```

テストデータ(irisの偶数行)
testData.csv

```
0.166666667,0.416666667,0.06779661,0.041666667
0.083333333,0.458333333,0.084745763,0.041666667
0.305555556,0.791666667,0.118644068,0.125
0.194444444,0.583333333,0.084745763,0.041666667
0.166666667,0.458333333,0.084745763,0
0.138888889,0.583333333,0.101694915,0.041666667
0,0.416666667,0.016949153,0
0.388888889,1,0.084745763,0.125
0.222222222,0.625,0.06779661,0.083333333
0.222222222,0.75,0.084745763,0.083333333
0.222222222,0.708333333,0.084745763,0.125
0.222222222,0.541666667,0.118644068,0.166666667
0.194444444,0.416666667,0.101694915,0.041666667
0.25,0.625,0.084745763,0.041666667
0.111111111,0.5,0.101694915,0.041666667
0.305555556,0.583333333,0.084745763,0.125
0.333333333,0.916666667,0.06779661,0.041666667
0.194444444,0.5,0.033898305,0.041666667
0.166666667,0.666666667,0.06779661,0
0.222222222,0.583333333,0.084745763,0.041666667
0.055555556,0.125,0.050847458,0.083333333
0.194444444,0.625,0.101694915,0.208333333
0.138888889,0.416666667,0.06779661,0.083333333
0.083333333,0.5,0.06779661,0.041666667
0.194444444,0.541666667,0.06779661,0.041666667
0.583333333,0.5,0.593220339,0.583333333
0.333333333,0.125,0.508474576,0.5
0.388888889,0.333333333,0.593220339,0.5
0.166666667,0.166666667,0.389830508,0.375
0.25,0.291666667,0.491525424,0.541666667
0.444444444,0.416666667,0.542372881,0.583333333
0.5,0.375,0.627118644,0.541666667
0.666666667,0.458333333,0.576271186,0.541666667
0.416666667,0.291666667,0.525423729,0.375
0.361111111,0.208333333,0.491525424,0.416666667
0.5,0.333333333,0.508474576,0.5
0.5,0.333333333,0.627118644,0.458333333
0.638888889,0.416666667,0.576271186,0.541666667
0.666666667,0.416666667,0.677966102,0.666666667
0.388888889,0.25,0.423728814,0.375
0.333333333,0.166666667,0.457627119,0.375
0.472222222,0.291666667,0.694915254,0.625
0.472222222,0.583333333,0.593220339,0.625
0.555555556,0.125,0.576271186,0.5
0.333333333,0.208333333,0.508474576,0.5
0.5,0.416666667,0.610169492,0.541666667
0.194444444,0.125,0.389830508,0.375
0.388888889,0.416666667,0.542372881,0.458333333
0.527777778,0.375,0.559322034,0.5
0.388888889,0.333333333,0.525423729,0.5
0.416666667,0.291666667,0.694915254,0.75
0.555555556,0.375,0.779661017,0.708333333
0.916666667,0.416666667,0.949152542,0.833333333
0.833333333,0.375,0.898305085,0.708333333
0.805555556,0.666666667,0.86440678,1
0.583333333,0.291666667,0.728813559,0.75
0.388888889,0.208333333,0.677966102,0.791666667
0.583333333,0.5,0.728813559,0.916666667
0.944444444,0.75,0.966101695,0.875
0.472222222,0.083333333,0.677966102,0.583333333
0.361111111,0.333333333,0.661016949,0.791666667
0.555555556,0.291666667,0.661016949,0.708333333
0.805555556,0.5,0.847457627,0.708333333
0.5,0.416666667,0.661016949,0.708333333
0.805555556,0.416666667,0.813559322,0.625
1,0.75,0.915254237,0.791666667
0.555555556,0.333333333,0.694915254,0.583333333
0.944444444,0.416666667,0.86440678,0.916666667
0.583333333,0.458333333,0.762711864,0.708333333
0.722222222,0.458333333,0.745762712,0.833333333
0.722222222,0.458333333,0.694915254,0.916666667
0.694444444,0.5,0.830508475,0.916666667
0.666666667,0.416666667,0.711864407,0.916666667
0.611111111,0.416666667,0.711864407,0.791666667
0.444444444,0.416666667,0.694915254,0.708333333
```

Comment: こんにちは。「うまくいかない」ということですが、どんな結果を期待して、それに反してどうなったのでしょうか。質問自体は興味深いのですが 直面している問題がなんなのか 質問からは読み取れませんでした。SOのヘルプセンターには質問する際の[ガイドライン](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)があります。ぜひ一度読んでみてください。そして質問を「編集」してみてください。ここでは質問の編集は推奨されています。そうすれば識者の人たちから回答が付きやすくなりますよ。

Comment: take88さん
ご指摘ありがとうございます。質問を編集してみたのですが、まだわかりにくいでしょうか。まだ至らぬ点があれば教えていただけると幸いです。

Comment: `readFileLabel` 関数ですが、3列の配列に対して scanf で4列読み込んでいますね(実行結果は変わりませんけれども)。

Comment: argusさん　ありがとうございます。readFileLabelの所を編集しました。

Comment: 見当違いだった様なので回答を削除しました。

Answer (score 1):

全部は読んでませんが、取りあえず気の付いたことだけ。

(1)
ファイルの読み込みで、以下の部分

```
while((inData=fgetc(fp))!=EOF){
    fscanf(fp,"%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf",&array[row][0],&array[row][1],&array[row][2],&array[row][3]);
    row++;
}
```

`inData=fgetc(fp)`で一文字が読み捨てられています。データが０．で始まるような場合はいいかもしれませんが、トレーニングラベルのような`1,0,0`で始まる場合問題になります。

それで、以下の様に変更します。

```
while(4==fscanf(fp,"%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf",&array[row][0],&array[row][1],&array[row][2],&array[row][3])){
    row++;
}
```

(2)
ファイルがオープンできなかった場合の処理として

```
}else{
    printf("Open error!!\n");
    fclose(fp);
}
```

のようにしていますが、この場合`fp`はオープンできなかったのでファイル構造体を指していない(NULL)ので`fclose`してはいけません。

Comment: BLUEPIXYさん
ありがとうございます。
編集しましたが、実行結果は変化しませんでした。

Comment: まあ、これだけが間違っている点として指摘したわけではありませんが、`readFileLabel` の場合データが１つ捨てられていて以降データが正しく読めていなかったわけですから変わらないというのも変ですけどもｗ